# Which answer is more acceptable for $\sqrt{48}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $2\sqrt{12}$ or $4\sqrt{3}$ a better representation? Also, for $\sqrt{675}$, is $3\sqrt{75}$ or $15\sqrt{3}$ considered more simplified? Why is one more simplified than the others?

Comment: I wouldn't want to commit to any of the possible forms, but I sort of have an idea of what $4\sqrt 3$ is, but $2\sqrt{12}$ not so much.

Comment: What is simplest or most convenient depends upon the context, e.g. if you wish to compare it to $\sqrt{47}$ then the form $\sqrt{48}$ is more convenient; if you wish to subtract $\,\sqrt{3}\,$ then the form $\,4\sqrt{3}\,$ is more convenient.

Comment: I agree with @Bill: it depends on the context. However, in the absence of any contextual information I would generally choose to pull as much out of the square root as possible, here $4\sqrt3$ and $15\sqrt3$. And in my experience extremes (e.g., $\sqrt{48}$ and $4\sqrt3$, and $\sqrt{675}$ and $15\sqrt3$) are likelier to be useful than intermediate forms like $2\sqrt{12}$.

Answer (score 5):

You would want to simplify the root as much as possible, removing all squares. You would want to use 4$\sqrt{3}$.

Further, the prime factorization of 48 is $2^4*3$, and that is what leads us to 4$\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: What is the root? There are the index, radicand, and the radical symbol, right?

Comment: The root is to the power of two, the base is 3. The four is just a coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it should be $4\sqrt 3$ or $\sqrt {48}$ .

Why should it be $\sqrt{48}$? You can get a very easy approximation of it just by knowing $\sqrt{49}=7$.

Why should it be $4\sqrt{3}$? You can calculate just by knowing $\sqrt{3}$. Which most mathematicians should know up to at least two places. (I don't though)

Comment: "Which most mathematicians should know up to at least two places." Why would they?

Comment: Having to calculate it a number of times and ending up with it engraved in your mind. It's not like they actually need to.